# Is low-rep flagging on popular tags counterproductive?

Tags: discussion, flags

I'm currently below the threshold for casting close votes directly - I'm limited to flagging questions for review.  I routinely flag duplicate and off-topic questions in some popular tags.  Most of these questions end up getting closed within a few hours of being posted.

Am I wasting the mods' time by flagging questions that are so likely to get closed by 3K+ users?  If I flag a question as off topic, and then the question is closed, is the off-topic flag automatically deleted?

Comment: Not sure how many you've submitted, but you have close to 200 helpful flags, so I imagine you're not using the system *totally* wrong. ;)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Unless you're using the "Other" flag option, Moderators are most likely *not* seeing your flags. They're ending up in the Close Votes review queue where reviewers (who, by definition, have enough reputation points to vote to close) will see the questions and can act on them.

So, no, you're not wasting Moderators' time. If your flag history is a long unbroken line of flags marked as "helpful", you're doing a good job.

Comment: So when I flag a question as off-topic, that doesn't count as a close vote - but it sends the question to the Close Votes queue where people who *can* vote to close can see it.  Is that right?

Comment: @BJM: That's correct.

Comment: @BJMyers Correct. Posts that are flagged with any option other than "Other" go to the [Low Quality Posts review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), which is available to users with 2,000 or more reputation.

Answer (score 19):

Neither of the flags go to mods.

Flagging as duplicate is very useful as it saves one time to find duplicate and provides faster closing.

Comment: Does flagging as duplicate when you don't have the rep auto-generate that comment "this may be a duplicate of FOO_BAR_BAZ"?

Comment: @Yakk - no idea (and I can't test it either), consider asking new question if it was not asked before.

Comment: @Yakk that's correct.